# Ubuntu version for XPS 13 touch screen

Tags: touchscreen, versions

Is there an Ubuntu version that will enable use of the touch screen on the current Dell XPS 13 with touch screen?

Comment: Can't you just check with live session?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

My HP Pro X2 612 touchscreen works fine with 15.10
No extra driver needed. Just the digitizer function sucks but that's no problem with the XPS 13.